# Strange java behaviour

Tags: java, behavior

Can anyone explain me this

```
int i=2;
int j=+-i;//-+i;
```

the value of `j=-2` in either case of `+-i` or `-+i`.

Is this fine in Java ? or should this be a compiler error?

Thankx in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's fine - you've just got two unary operators together. So it's either:

```
int j = +(-i);
```

or

```
int j = -(+i);
```

See [sections 15.15.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.15.3) and [15.15.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.15.4) of the JLS for these two operators.

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely fine. Go through the [Unary Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) in java

Both the cases are similar, the ultimate result stays same with the same operations performed in different order!!

Answer (score 2):

just think of it this way: `int j = +i` would correspond to `int j = i`. Therefore, `-+i` or `+-i` would be `-i`.

Answer (score 2):

You're applying two unary operators to `i`:

```
int j = +-i;
```

is equivalent to

```
int j = +(-i);
```

and similarly for `-+i`. The outcome is the same as negating `i` unless `i` is equal to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (in which case `j` ends up equal to `i`).